# After mod_rewirte: Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error

Tags: cakephp, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

I'm encountering the following problem. I had this error in Cakephp
 "URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server". The solution was adding this line

> Options FollowSymLinks
>       AllowOverride All

to the 000-default.conf file /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

The cakephp included css but when I try to access my localhost I'm getting the error:
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. 
To make it to work I have to delete the alteration in the 000-default.conf file.

How can I fix it to make both work?

the code of my 000-default.conf

```js
<VirtualHost *:80>
 # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
 # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
 # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
 # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
 # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
 # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
 # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
 #ServerName www.example.com

 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    
    <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

 # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
 # error, crit, alert, emerg.
 # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
 # modules, e.g.
 #LogLevel info ssl:warn

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

 # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
 # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
 # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
 # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
 # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
 #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

app/tmp/log/error.log:

```
2014-10-03 04:58:58 Error: [MissingActionException] Action UsersController::index() could not be found.
```

Exception Attributes: array (
  'controller' => 'UsersController',
  'action' => 'index',
)
Request URL: /cakephp/acl_1/Users
Stack Trace:

## 0 /var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(191): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))

## 1 /var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(165): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(UsersController), Object(CakeRequest))

## 2 /var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/app/webroot/index.php(108): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))

## 3 {main}

2014-10-03 07:16:50 Error: Fatal Error (1): Unsupported operand types in [/var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php, line 1802]
2014-10-03 07:16:50 Error: [FatalErrorException] Unsupported operand types
Request URL: /cakephp/acl_1/users/view/1
Stack Trace:

## 0 /var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(203): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(1, 'Unsupported ope...', '/var/www/html/c...', 1802)

## 1 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleError(1, 'Unsupported ope...', '/var/www/html/c...', 1802, Array)

## 2 /var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(929): call_user_func('ErrorHandler::h...', 1, 'Unsupported ope...', '/var/www/html/c...', 1802, Array)

## 3 /var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(902): App::_checkFatalError()

## 4 [internal function]: App::shutdown()

## 5 {main}

2014-10-03 07:19:19 Error: Fatal Error (1): Unsupported operand types in [/var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php, line 1802]
2014-10-03 07:19:19 Error: [FatalErrorException] Unsupported operand types
Request URL: /cakephp/acl_1/users/edit/1
Stack Trace:

## 0 /var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(203): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(1, 'Unsupported ope...', '/var/www/html/c...', 1802)

## 1 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleError(1, 'Unsupported ope...', '/var/www/html/c...', 1802, Array)

## 2 /var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(929): call_user_func('ErrorHandler::h...', 1, 'Unsupported ope...', '/var/www/html/c...', 1802, Array)

## 3 /var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(902): App::_checkFatalError()

## 4 [internal function]: App::shutdown()

## 5 {main}

2014-10-03 07:22:04 Error: Fatal Error (1): Unsupported operand types in [/var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php, line 1802]
2014-10-03 07:22:04 Error: [FatalErrorException] Unsupported operand types
Request URL: /cakephp/acl_1/users/edit/2
Stack Trace:

## 0 /var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(203): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(1, 'Unsupported ope...', '/var/www/html/c...', 1802)

## 1 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleError(1, 'Unsupported ope...', '/var/www/html/c...', 1802, Array)

## 2 /var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(929): call_user_func('ErrorHandler::h...', 1, 'Unsupported ope...', '/var/www/html/c...', 1802, Array)

## 3 /var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(902): App::_checkFatalError()

## 4 [internal function]: App::shutdown()

## 5 {main}

2014-10-03 07:28:35 Error: Fatal Error (1): Unsupported operand types in [/var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php, line 1802]
2014-10-03 07:28:35 Error: [FatalErrorException] Unsupported operand types
Request URL: /cakephp/acl_1/users/edit/3
Stack Trace:

## 0 /var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(203): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(1, 'Unsupported ope...', '/var/www/html/c...', 1802)

## 1 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleError(1, 'Unsupported ope...', '/var/www/html/c...', 1802, Array)

## 2 /var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(929): call_user_func('ErrorHandler::h...', 1, 'Unsupported ope...', '/var/www/html/c...', 1802, Array)

## 3 /var/www/html/cakephp/acl_1/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(902): App::_checkFatalError()

## 4 [internal function]: App::shutdown()

## 5 {main}

Comment: Please post your complete 000-default as it is now - and read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

Comment: I poted it. I'v already solved the problem with the first error with the aid of your link before

Comment: That's good. I'll be posting the same comment as an answer and mark it as accepted so the solutions stays for future reference.

Comment: but it is still not working. Should I accept the answer although my problem is no solved?

Comment: I meant hier the first error "URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server" that I had before I solved it with your link but not the second error of the title

Comment: Please include `<app>/tmp/logs/error.log` (of course not everything in there, only what is connected to your specific question).

Comment: where should I include it in the 000-default.conf file and how to include it?

Comment: I meant include the relevant information inside it in your question.

Comment: In this file are just the errors from today 03.10.14 and not the days before and I'm working on my cakephp so there are just normal errors from today. can i remove the path var/www/html from this line "<Directory /var/www/html>" --> "Directory"?

Comment: As I said I do not have problem with cakephpbut with accessing of the localhost.